# Getting subfigures side-by-side in multi-column environment with sub-numbering

Tags: floats, subfloats

this is my first time posting here so please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in my post.

I am trying to get three figures side by side in a two column environment (spanning over the two columns), and have been able to successfully do so, but the figures compile as separate (i.e. the numbering goes Fig 1, Fig 2, Fig 3 instead of 1.1, 1.2, 1.3). I would like there to be sub-numbering instead of different numbers. The template is from a Springer journal, so I have a hard time modifying the template. Things like `\usepackage{subcaption}` do not seem compatible with the template.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a}\par\caption{caption}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b}\par\caption{caption}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c}\par\caption{caption}
\end{multicols}
\end{figure*}
```

When I do it this way, I get three Figures side by side that look nice, but I want them to be subfigures, i.e. overall all three would be one figure with one caption, and then there would be three sub-labels/captions. Can anyone help me figure this out? Seems like a quick fix but the template I'm forced to use is a nightmare and all the simple fixes I've found online cause the program to freak out.

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add the documentclass in order to make your example code compilable? (See: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Use `subfigure` or `subfloat` environments from `subcaptionn` or `subfig` package respectively.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following solution gives what you after for:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document delete option "demo"
\usepackage{subcaption}% <--- new

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a}
\caption{sub caption 1}
\label{fig:figure-a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b}
\caption{sub caption 2}
\label{fig:figure-b}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c}
    \caption{sub caption 3}
\label{fig:figure-c}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{fig:figure}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]